# Accessing prop properties in ready()?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am getting `undefined` in the console that is coming from `ready()`

I am trying to copy the value from `this.users.name` to  `this.userForm.name`

What I am doing wrong?

**profile-user Component**

```
   <template>
      <input type="text" v-model="userForm.name">
   </template>

<script>
    export default {

        props: ['users'],

        ready() {
            this.userForm.name = this.users.name;
            console.log(this.users.name);
        },

        data: function () {
            return {
                userForm: {
                    name: '',
                    email: '',
                    errors: [],
                },
            }
        },
} 
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<profile-user :users="users"></profile-user>
```

Edit:

**Parent Vue**

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: 'body',
    data: {
        users: {}
    },

    ready: function() {
        this.fetchUser();
    },

    methods: {
        fetchUser: function() {
            this.$http.get('/api/user').then(response => this.users = response.json());
        }
    },
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ready` is deprecated in Vue 2.0. You need to use `mounted` instead of `ready()`

Reference for migrating from 1.x: https://vuejs.org/guide/migration.html#ready-replaced

Another potential problem: is your `users` an array item? If it is an object, then you can consider naming it more appropriately as `user_info`. But if you are passing a single user info into `users` with a `name` parameter on it, then your code should technically work.

If you do not have vue-devtools already, now is probably a good time to install and debug in dev console: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools

**EDIT: modified after question changes**

Thanks for providing Parent component. I think I can see the issue now:

Let's say your `$http` call takes about 500 milliseconds to complete. So your `this.users` in parent component will be undefined for the first 500 milliseconds. But your child component (`profile-user`) is already created by then. And it will try to access `userForm.name` which is undefined till server response comes.

To avoid the problem, you may do as follows in the template of `profile-user` component:

```html
<template>
    <div v-if="userForm">
        <input type="text" v-model="userForm.name">
    </div>
    <div v-else>
        Loading user data... Please wait
    </div>
</template>
```

In your dev environment, it will probably not take much time for server to respond. But still the `this.$http` call is asynchronous - AJAX call will be initiated only after the `profile-user` component is fully created.

Comment: More info on Vue instance lifecycle: https://vuejs.org/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram - so now you know when `mounted` is called. You can also notice that there is no `ready` anymore.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have found the problem and I am looking for a way to solve this. Basically on the parent vue it is fetching user via Ajax and `this.users.name` from component couldnt read it because ajax is not completed from parent. How we can solve this?

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: Updated my answer. You will just have to wait till data comes from server in parent component, before accessing `user.name` in child component.

Comment: I've been using `created` instead of `mounted` without a problem. After the component's data structure is fully `created`, we can fiddle its data safely, whether it's mounted to the dom or not.

Comment: @潘俊杰 Yes, created happens a bit earlier than mounted in the life-cycle of a component. In the case of fetching some server data using `this.$http`, it does not make a big difference whether we use `created` or `mounted`, as long as we do not use `ready` which is deprecated in [Vue 2.0](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2873)

Comment: @Mani Tried your solution and that didnt fix it. However, managed to get it work using this solution: `<profile-user  v-if="users.name" :users="users" ></profile-user>`

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back Yes, my solution will not work till you remove `this.userForm.name = this.users.name;` from your `ready` function in profile-user component. Problem is, `this.users.name` will remain undefined till your API call finishes and you initialize `this.users` in the parent component.